# Query depends on another query inside

Tags: mysql, notin

I having a problem with a query inside another one.

One table as question and the other one has que questions used by the users.
So I'm Trying to query a new question but only if is not in the used question table.

In this example looks like its working, but i have more than 1000 question on the db Table and cant see if the result is not in the result.

```
SELECT * FROM questions 
WHERE id NOT IN 
    (SELECT QiD FROM Usedquestion) 
ORDER BY RAND() 
LIMIT 1
```

Can some one send me a light?

Comment: so what is you question?

Comment: It is not really clear what you are after. You should add some sample data, results returned by your above query, and the expected results on the sample data. This way we can check what may have gone wrong.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT q.id,u.QiD
FROM questions q
LEFT OUTER JOIN Usedquestion u ON u.QiD = q.id
WHERE u.QiD IS NULL
```

This will show you the questions in the question table that do not have an id in the usedquestion table.

Comment: Thansk devlin.Your example is giving me a result only if id exist on the 2 tables.

Comment: this it seems to be working.

SELECT q. * , u.QiD FROM questions q LEFT OUTER JOIN Usedq u ON u.QiD != q.id WHERE u.QiD ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1

its correct?

Comment: @Agent_x - my example should give you records that only exist in the questions table and do not exist in the Usedquestion table.  That is, unless QiD is not the foreign key for the question id.  If it's not the foreign key, you'll need to explain how the two tables are related.

Comment: Yep , its working now, the query only pick a question if the question id is not in the used questions table.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  a FROM questions a LEFT JOIN Usedquestion b USING(id)
WHERE b.id is null
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;
```